# Beginner: Broke my head trying to accomplish my idea with do while loop

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

Idea is to print the table with id="gameTable" 6 times. Each time 180px right from the one printed before. Using CSS properties. Doesnt work and i dont know why. I feel it is something simple I connot see. But what?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleTable.css">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function newPage(){
    document.open();
    document.write('<HTML>');
    document.write('<head>');
    document.write('</head>');
document.write('<body>');
var i = 0;
function schedule () {
/* print the table */
document.write('<table id="gameTable">');
document.write('<tr>');
document.write('<td id="gameCellTeamNameHost">Arsenal</td>');
document.write('<td id="gameCellTeamNameDash"> - </td>');
document.write('<td id="gameCellTeamNameGuest">Chelsea</td>');
document.write('</tr>');
document.write('<tr>');
document.write('<td id="gameCellScoreHost">0</td>');
document.write('<td id="gameCellScoreSemicolon">:</td>');
document.write('<td id="gameCellScoreGuest">3</td>');
document.write('</tr>   ');
document.write('</table>');
/*Style*/
document.getElementById("gameTable").style.height = "50px"; 
document.getElementById("gameTable").style.width = "180px"; 
document.getElementById("gameTable").style.border = "1px";
document.getElementById("gameTable").style.borderStyle = "solid";   
document.getElementById("gameTable").style.borderColor = "black";
document.getElementById("gameTable").style.padding = "5px"; 
document.getElementById("gameTable").style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
document.getElementById("gameTable").style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById("gameTable").style.top = "110px";
/* this is the line i used var i */
document.getElementById("gameTable").style.left = (i+"px");
/* -----------------*/
document.getElementById("gameCellTeamNameHost").style.textAlign = "left";
document.getElementById("gameCellTeamNameHost").style.verticalAlign = "top";
document.getElementById("gameCellTeamNameHost").style.height = "24px";
document.getElementById("gameCellTeamNameHost").style.width = "80px";
document.getElementById("gameCellTeamNameGuest").style.textAlign = "right";
document.getElementById("gameCellTeamNameGuest").style.verticalAlign = "top";
document.getElementById("gameCellTeamNameGuest").style.height = "24px";
document.getElementById("gameCellTeamNameGuest").style.width = "80px";
}
 do {           
    schedule();
        i +=180;
        }
        while (i < 1081);

document.write('</body>');
document.write('</HTML>');
document.close();
   }
   </SCRIPT>
   </HEAD>  
   <BODY>
   <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="New Season" ONCLICK="newPage()">
   </BODY>
   </HTML>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine? http://jsfiddle.net/ZGAJs/

Comment: You cannot use document.write after page load. Create a div and use innerHTML

Comment: Also pointless to write html, head and body tags into a document that already has these tags

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. First off, you should not be relying on `document.write`, you should instead be doing `document.createElement` or using a framework like jQuery to dynamically create your tables.

Additionally, you should not be using the same `id="gameTable"` over and over again. You should instead be using classes, e.g., `class="gameTable"`. Because you are using the same id more than once, when you apply your styles with `document.getElementById("gameTable")`, you're not applying them to all the tables, only the first one that is returned.

And lastly, you don't need to rely on absolute positioning, a simple style like this will align the tables the way you want them:

```
.gameTable
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 180px;
}
```

Comment: thank you. you cleared up a lot in my head. with these classes and ids.

Comment: unfortunately i dont know JQuery yet. But I will take a look to innerHTML. CSS code you are provided didnt change the situation. I wanted to insert as many tables as I desire to one next to another. That's why I used a JS function. Well, I will try to play more with that.

Comment: basically I wanted to repeat this html code
    <table class="gameTable" onmouseover="gameTableOnMouseOver ()">
      <tr class="gameCellTeamName">
 <td class="gameCellTeamNameHost">Arsenal</td>
 <td class="gameCellTeamNameDash"> - </td>
 <td class="gameCellTeamNameGuest">Chelsea</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
 <td class="gameCellScoreHost">0</td>
 <td class="gameCellScoreSemicolon">:</td>
 <td class="gameCellScoreGuest">3</td>
 </tr>    
    </table>

inside the <div calss="gameField"> As many times as i want for example 6 in a row, 4 rows. Can anyone help me with that or need more information?